# Track branch after creation?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

Here's my scenario (it's a very simple one): I have created a branch locally, without using `--track`. I made a few commits and pushed it like so:

```
git push origin test
```

But now I don't want to have to type `origin test` everytime I push this branch, so I'd like to have it track `origin/test` (or is it the other way around?).

How can I achieve this? I tried:

```
git branch --set-upstream origin/test
```

and it didn't work. When I try to push it says "everything up to date", and it seems to have created an actual branch called "origin/test", which is not what I want.

**Update:** here are the contents of `.git/config` (after running `--set-upstream`):

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@***.unfuddle.***/***.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/unfuddle/*
    push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[gui]
    wmstate = normal
    geometry = 1098x644+298+187 207 207
[branch "test"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually editing `.git/config`. Here's what it looks like now:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@***.unfuddle.***/***.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/unfuddle/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "test"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/test
```

Seems to work now. I got the example from another project where I've set up the branches using `--track`.

I think the problem lied with the `push` statement in `[remote "origin"]`, I think that made it always push the master branch.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to specifiy the local branch when calling `git branch --set-uptstream`

```
git branch --set-upstream test origin/test
```

Edit:
OK, maybe you didn't forget it (because the last argument can be omitted), but you want to set the local branch to track the remote one ([manpage git-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html)), instead you did the opposite (assuming that you are currently on the branch `test`)

```
git branch [--set-upstream | --track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
```

You specify, that `origin/test` track `test`.

Comment: This did not work. Doing `git push` after this command yielded "everything is up to date" although I had made commits after the last push.

Comment: Copy&Paste commenting? You are sure, that you executed the comment in my answer, and not the one from @Aasmund ? Whats in your `.git/config`? There should be something like `[branch "test"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/test`

Comment: Yes. I copied & pasted because I got the same behavior with both commands.

Comment: Just tried the other way around as well (`--set-upstream origin/test test`) and I get the same thing.

Comment: You will need to delete the local origin/test branch that was created with the incorrect command for this to work.  I believe the correct order is <old-branch> <new-branch> for set-upstream but if the local origin/test branch still exists it will effectively shadow the branch test of remote origin.

Comment: Still nothing. If I do that, `--set-upstream test origin/test` says `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/test'.` If I do `--set-upstream test remotes/unfuddle/test` (this is how `branch -a` lists it), it works, but `push` says everything up to date.

Comment: However, `status` says "Your branch is ahead of 'unfuddle/test' by 1 commit."

Comment: Just to make that clear: Your remote is named `unfuddle` and not `origin`?!

Comment: Unfuddle is a git hosting / issue tracker service, which is why the remotes are named unfuddle. However, `git push origin test` works. Also, `.git/config` defines a `[remote "origin"]`.

Answer (score 1):

`--set-upstream` has been deprecated.  Use `--track` or `--set-upstream-to` instead.

```
git branch --track test origin/test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `git push -u origin test`.

Comment: This did not work. Doing `git push` after this command yielded "everything is up to date" although I had made commits after the last push.